# My cycle render result is far different from my viewport how can I solve it

Tags: error

[image]

left is my render result and right is viewport why are they so different
I want the result of right version not left

blender file is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q90wzIHG0yZwDQTdKmcXqJnCWGrF3ny8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add a few more details and provide your .blend file.

Comment: hmm, so what result do you want, the one in the render or in the viewport ?

Answer (score 0):

It's something strange. On my end, the image renders properly.[image]

On the other hand, when I render an animation this error comes.[image]

Edit: I think the change of colours is because you rendered the animation in eevee before and then are viewing it in cycles in the viewport.